# ld linker script error

Tags: linux, linker, gnu

The project I'm currently working on uses a bunch of dynamic libs bundled together with the source code. There is a subset of libs which is named as follows:

for a given lib libABC, there are four files:

libABC.so

libABC.so.4

libABC.so.4.5

libABC.so.4.5.0

They are daisy-chained like this:

the first file, libABC.so, contains the following:

```
link libABC.so.4
```

whereas the next file, libABC.so.4, contains the following:

```
link libABC.so.4.5
```

and so on till the actual lib file, libABC.so.4.5.0.

I know that this kind of stuff should be done using symlinks, but we can't change that, it's a commercial project. So the linker chokes on that!

```
/usr/bin/ld: path/to/the/packaged/libs/libABC.so:unrecognized file format, treating as linker script
```

(which it actually is, heh)

```
/usr/bin/ld: path/to/the/packaged/libs/libABC.so:1:syntax error
```

Now I can't seem to find any info on the GNU ld linker script command "link" or any complete reference to the GNU ld linker script commands.

What could that be?

Comment: My, haven't you got spunk! You really should just read the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker script format is described in the [GNU ld manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts).

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue myself today, and what happens is when you do a checkout using SVN on Windows (e.g. TortoiseSVN), the Linux symlink is converted into a text file.

Then, on the build process, ld is receiving a text file instead of a symlink that would lead to the concrete file.

Solution: svn checkout on the Linux machine.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue. Used Git to checkout code under windows and mounted it as volumne in a docker linux container... Checking out from the container directly indeed solves the issue...